# File include operation in B&R Automation Studio

Tags: c, boolean, plc, ansi-c, br-automation-studio

I have an Automation Studio project in which I include .h and .c files, I use the ANSI C standard. There are certain errors I get while doing the include operations, but what I wonder about this issue is that I added the files with the referenced file option when adding them to the project. For this reason, a corresponding .pkg file was created in Automation Studio. When I do #include for this file, should I write #include according to the path of the file or according to the file path where this pkg file is located?

Since there are too many .c and .h files in my project, I tried to comment most of the project, but it did not work. the errors I received are as follows.  I used #include <stdbool.h> for boolean errors, but I would like you to tell me if there are any points I should pay attention to.

Comment: You `#include` the *header* file, not the "pkg" file.

Comment: Do you know what is the difference between adding a file to a project with the referenced file option and adding it as a direct file?